# Excel VBA : cells change values depending on specific groups (expanded or collapsed)

Tags: excel, vba

I'd like to modify values on specific cells depending on a specific group if it's expanded or collapsed.

I found a way, but it's a manual way [(image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMzj8.png) [image2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLmln.png) (the macro needs to be launched on each run).

Is there a way to use a function (i.e. *worksheet_change*), so that will be on real time ?

P.S. Sorry for my bad English and be kind, I'm kinda new on VBA (first code).

Thank you.

```
Private Sub groups()

    If Worksheets("Feuil1").Columns("F").ShowDetail = True Then
    Range("K2:K7").Value = "YES"

    Else
    Range("K2:K7").Value = "NO"

    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Luuklag for your solution, but as I said in my comment, in your code I have to update manually the placeholder cell which is not what I'm looking for.

But, I found something where my cells get updated by expanding or collapsing my group. And for this, as you said, I need a placeholder cell that gets updated on each calculation.

I use the formula `=NOW` on cell `A1`, because it's always useful to know the time and date.
Here is the (combined) code, for those who are looking a solution :

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    'Where F is the column having the group button
    If Columns("F").ShowDetail = True Then

    'This is where you choose the cells that are dependent to the group and attribute something
    Range("G10:G19").Value = "YES"

    Else
    'Same here. It could be other cells too
    Range("G10:G19").Value = "NO"

    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple solution to this. Every time you expand or collapse a group you trigger the worksheet_calculate event. This can be used to your advantage.

All you need is a placeholder cell, which you populate with a volatile function (a function that changes its value on each calculation). You can use `=randbetween(1,10)` or `=NOW()` for example.

You then have your worksheet change event to look for your placeholder cell, `AA1` in this example.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   If Not Intersect(Target, Range("AA1")) Is Nothing Then
      Call groups
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Your code almost works : the cells change, but they do not depend on the group button. I need to enter to the placeholder cell, refresh it manually and then the cells look if the group is expanded or collapsed.

I wanted the cells to be totally dependant on the group button.